# How to override Rails' using "id" as a table's primary key?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postfix-mta

Rails 5.2.1

I have a Postfix mail server that I set up according to the guide at [flurdy.com](http://flurdy.com). It uses MySQL on the back end to keep track of virtual domains, users, and mapping aliases to user accounts. I'm trying to put a nice Rails front end on the MySQL tables it uses.

[Flurdy's method](http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/index.html) uses a field called "id" to store the email address of a user. My problem, of course, is that Rails likes to use "id" as the primary key for a table. I found a guide to using a different primary key, but even after doing `db:migrate` on my users table and specifying in the model that it should use 'pkid' as the primary key, instead of giving me a list of email addresses, I get the value of pkid. The email addresses are correct in MySQL.

Here's the relevant snippet of the Users table migration:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :users, id: false do |t|
      t.primary_key :pkid
      t.string :id
      t.string :name

 . . . skip . . . 

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And here's the Users model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  self.primary_key = 'pkid'
end
```

Expected behavior would be to see something like this when I call up users#index:

```
pkid  id                    name
1     this@example.com      This User
2     that@example.com      That User
3     theother@example.com  Someone Else
```

And what I'm seeing instead:

```
pkid  id                    name
1     1                     This User
2     2                     That User
3     3                     Someone Else
```

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: I set up a link above to Flurdy's guide to setting up Postfix to serve virtual domains on GNU/Linux. It uses MySQL to store user, domain and alias information, sometimes replacing hash tables in the /etc/postfix directory, to add a bit of context to this issue.

Comment: Calling it literally `id` is a bad plan. Doing this on the users table is especially a bad plan.

Comment: How does Flurdy's method integrate with Rails? Where does this "id" value get used?

Comment: @tadman (1) Bad plan? Duly noted, but this setup dates back to years before I thought of trying to manage it with a Rails app. (2) How does it integrate with Rails? it doesn't. This is something I decided I'd like to do independently of his (well known) Postfix howto guide. Explaining will take a lot more space than this comment allows.

Comment: You have an opportunity at the interfacing to map `id` to something else as actually stored in the record, or to make your database record export a compatible structure. For example, `to_flurdy` could return a Hash with `{ id: ..., ... }` to represent that in the expected form. If you need a full-fledged Object with methods you can call, you can trivially wrap that in `OpenStruct` so `obj.id` works.

Comment: why do you still need `pkid` ?

Comment: @LamPhan I'm not sure I do still need a pkid. The Postfix system doesn't use one. However Rails by convention creates a primary key when it migrates a table, and it's not impossible I might want to extend this system in the future, in which case the pkid will be easier to use for relations into the User table than the actual ID/email address. But that's a problem for another day.

Comment: @tadman Thanks, I'll give that some thought.

Comment: If you can avoid rewriting the `id` field you'll be in much, *much* better shape down the road.

Comment: @tadman My plan at the moment is to duplicate the "id" column and give it the name "email", then test modifying all of the configurations/queries that reference that field. At worst I'll have to keep the two columns in sync. At best I can delete the "id" column and post a guide to Github for those who want to do something similar.

Comment: Calling it what it is makes a lot more sense, and aliasing, if necessary, for export. There's nothing worse than having a non-standard ID column as it can make all relationships with that table very awkward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the id attribute is now aliased to the pkid attribute.

To see the value of the id column you can use the attributes hash:

```rb
    User.first.attributes["id"]
```

Comment: That looks like it should work. Off to give it a try and see if I can insert a record this way. Thank you!!